# ?Can we add a searchbar in start menu in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, start-menu, windows-search

My question is simple. I just wanted to add the windows search bar in start menu. I dont want the two clicks to open the search bar. I just want to see it on one click. Can you please tell me if it is possible do that?

[image]

Comment: Try pressing `F3`.

Comment: You don't have to use 2 clicks. Just click on "Start" button (either on keyboard, or on screen), and start typing. You never really need to click on the magnifying glass icon (search icon).

Comment: It work but not intuitive that is why I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the mouse to the bottom left and click, or press the <kbd>win</kbd> key, you get the start menu. From there you can just start typing and the search bar automatically shows up.

If you really want to have it more like windows 7, you'll need a program such as [Classic Start Menu](http://www.classicshell.net/downloads/) which is part of the `Classic Shell` programs.

This will give you a start menu replacement with a search bar that you can click in with extra options to configure. The start menu will contain a link to the Metro interface.